# Unable to boot into Ubunutu after firmware update

Tags: dual-boot, windows, firmware

I have been booting into Ubuntu 20.04 for some time now on a Dell Latitude computer also running Windows 10 Enterprise. I restarted the computer just now and it attempted a firmware update then shut off (not sure if the update was successful.) When I turn it on again I see the error:

> `start_image() returned an invalid parameter`

I can boot into Windows normally but can't access Ubuntu. What happened? What do I do?

Comment: This worked: https://askubuntu.com/questions/975935/dual-boot-dell-xps-13-fails-to-boot-into-ubuntu-after-firmware-update

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dual boot Dell XPS 13 fails to boot into Ubuntu after firmware update](https://askubuntu.com/questions/975935/dual-boot-dell-xps-13-fails-to-boot-into-ubuntu-after-firmware-update)